# How to Query a Web Service (XML) From a Subreport?

Tags: ssrs-2008, reporting-services

I apologize if this has been already asked but my searches have had little luck. I've also tried MSDN forum's, but its obvious that I need the big guns for this one ;)

I am using VS2008 (SSRS 2008 R2) to create a series of subreports.  Each Subreport queries 1 or more Web Methods from a WCF Web Service.

When I run an rdl as a stand-alone report, everything renders properly. When I run that rdl as a subreport, I receive an error recommending that I check the log (details, and steps to reproduce below.)

**Simple Test (No Subreports):**

Using the instructions found in the article [Reporting Services: Using XML and Web Service Data Sources](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-US/library/aa964129%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx) I was able to create the necessary Shared Datasets for each web method.

I successfully created a report (SubTest.rdl) utilizing a Shared Dataset for a Table.
The dataset's underlying web method contains no parameters (trying to keep it simple).

SubTest.rdl renders correctly!
So far so good.

**Test 2: Master/Subreport structure**

1. created a Parent/Master report (MasterTest.rdl)
2. added a Subreport Report Item, and specified "SubTest.rdl"

   Note: No Report parameters are specified, as SubTest does not have any parameters defined.

I receive the following error during the rendering of the MasterTest.rdl report:

*Warning    1    [rsErrorExecutingSubreport] An error occurred while executing the subreport 'Subreport1' (Instance: 5iS0): Data retrieval failed for the subreport, 'Subreport1', located at: /SubTest. Please check the log files for more information.*

**Additional Testing:**

To ensure that my subreport is properly defined in MasterTest.rdl, I altered SubTest.rdl.  In SubTest I removed the DataSource, DataSet, and Table from "SubTest.rdl" and insterted a TextBox filled with the words "Output From Subreport".  This rendered properly in the Master report, indicating that the problem specifically relates to my Web Service Datasource/DataSet.

**Questions:  :(**

- Is there a way to accomplish this task?
- If this is not possible, can anyone suggest a workaround for providing Web Service xml to a subreport?
- Also, per the error message: Any idea where I can find this log? (because this is running in Visual Studio, checking the SSRS logs folder on my local machine did not help, nor did running VS with logging enabled.)

**A workaround that I could not get to work:**
I tried to follow the instructions in the linked article for passing XML to a subreport as a parameter, but

- The master passes the xml as a scalar string.  Because I am querying
  a web service and not using a data set where each row contains a col holding the XML,  I only have the resultant dataset to work with. Basically I need to convert a data set to a scalar.
- I had difficulty following the instructions (even if I could solve problem
  1, I'm not even sure that I properly defined the dataset and
  parameter - how do I get fields when the data is not known until
  runtime?)

Thank you for any help you can give.  This has been driving nuts for days!